# Android Studio - Trying to Read MP3 FIles from the Music Directory on Android Device

Tags: java, android-studio, mediastore

I have a function below that I got from a post on here, where I am trying to read the music files from the device.

```
   public List<AudioModel> getAllAudioFromDevice(final Context context) {
        final List<AudioModel> tempAudioList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor c = getAllTracks(this);


        if (c != null) {
            Log.d("Count :", String.valueOf(c.getCount()));
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                AudioModel audioModel = new AudioModel();
                String path = c.getString(0);
                String name = c.getString(1);
                String album = c.getString(4);

                audioModel.setaAlbum(album);
                audioModel.setaArtist(artist);
       
                Log.e("Name :" + name, " Album :" + album);
                Log.e("Path :" + path, " Artist :" + artist);

                tempAudioList.add(audioModel);
            }
            c.close();
        } else {
            Log.d("Name :", "No Music");
        }

        return tempAudioList;
    }

    public Cursor getAllTracks(Context context) {
        // gets all tracks
        if (context != null) {
            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            final String[] columns = {track_id, track_no, artist, track_name,
                    album, duration, path, year, composer};
            return cr.query(uri, columns, null, null, null);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When I run the app, it doesn't list any of the MP3 files, but it picks up oog files. The mp3 files I have uploaded to the emulator look as below:

[image: Emulator storage image one]

[image: Emulator storage image two]

I have tried the EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI as well, but that doesn't display them.

This is from the "Playlist Manager" app as suggested by Theo:

[image]

Sorry, I am very new to Android Studio and am probably missing something very obvious. Can someone help please?

Comment: I have also added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> to the manifest file.

Comment: Looks ok, try and reboot the avd as this will ensure a fresh media scan. If you just uploaded them then the device is probably unaware of new media

Comment: Hi Theo, I have tried that, but it still doesn't pick them up. On the emulator I can see the music files under storage so it looks like the device is detecting them.

Comment: Query BUCKET_NAME too.

Comment: Place some files directly in the Music dir.

Comment: Please remove the android-studio tag and remove it from the subject. Add an android tag.

Comment: `On the emulator I can see the music files under storage` It is unclear which app you use for that. Further try a Gallery or Music app.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean by "BUCKET_NAME", can you provide an example? Can you explain why I need to remove the android-studio tag. I am developing an app with Android Studio, the app needs to read the music files. This is a question about querying media files in Android Studio using Java, not to do with Android general use.

Comment: @RLBChrisBriant, can I suggest you try my free app Free New Playlist Manager and check in the Library view if all your tracks show up. The app interrogates the android media database so it would prove all your tracks are there

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
```

change this to

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
```

and also remove the .DATA bit from
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, null, null)
as you put criteria there. Look up the syntax for query. Set it to null and it will work

Comment: Unfortunately, this also doesn't work. I have since changed the code a lot and will update it with what I have now which was basically taken from someone else's blog on this subject.

Comment: I've edited with the different function that I tried from a different blog post. It is different from what I originally posted, but it also doesn't work. The "Music count" log is always at 0, regardless of whether it is INTERNAL or EXTERNAL.

Comment: If your music count = 0 then there are no .mp3 files in the database. Did you try my playlist manager suggestion? that will definitely show you if you have tracks in the media database. My code has worked fine for the last 5 years so if you stick to it it will work

Comment: Hi Theo, thanks for your reply. I modified my code to reflect your answer and edited the post to show what it looks like now. I do apologize as I am very, very new to Android Development. I am not sure what you mean by "playlist manager". Sorry, it is my lack of understanding of Android development, I have only been doing it for a month in my spare time. If it is okay, could you explain with an example?

Comment: Playlist manager is my app on google play. It is free so download it and see what it produces

Comment: Hi Theo, I have tried Playlist Manager from the Google App store and that is able to display the music files on the emulator. I have uploaded an image from the device into my main post.

Comment: Chris, the playlist manager app you are showing is not my app so i cannot categorically state that what you show comes from the android mediastore. My app is called Free New Playlist Manager by flyingdutchman If you simply use the code i provided and c.getcount() is 0 then there are no tracks.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth - I had the exact same problem. I added my audio files to the emulator using the Device File Explorer and the code didn't seem to work.
It turns out that I had to simply **reboot my emulator after adding the files in order for the uploaded files to appear in the MediaStore data base**.
I don't know if this is a bug or a feature in Android Studio and/or the emulator, but in my case it fixed the issue. I tested it on two different emulator sessions (one with SDK31 and the other SDK29).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This is my approach, note the syntax of

```
return cr.query(uri, columns, null, null, null)
```

whereas you have

```
  Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, null, null);



 private final String track_id = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
    private final String track_no = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK;
    private final String track_name = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
    private final String artist = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST;
    private final String artist_id = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID;
    private final String duration = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION;
    private final String album = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM;
    private final String composer = MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER;
    private final String year = MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR;
    private final String path = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
    private final String date_added = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED;
    private final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;


        public Cursor getAllTracks(Context context) {
        // gets all tracks
        if (context != null) {
            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            final String[] columns = {track_id, track_no, artist, track_name,
                    album, duration, path, year, composer};
            return cr.query(uri, columns, null, null, null);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Theo, many thanks, I will give that a go and let you know if it works or not. Hopefully, I will be able to tomorrow, I will keep you updated.

Comment: Hi Theo, I have changed my code to include your suggestion, but it is still the same. I have updated my question to reflect the changes made based on your suggestion. The value of count when it is logged is still "showing 2020-09-04 07:24:39.559 15448-15448/com.example.musicbox D/Count :: 0". I am not sure if I have implemented your suggestion correctly though. I'm new to Java and Android Studio so I might not be getting your answer right.

Comment: You  are not retrieving the correct columns. Path is not position 0, name is not position 1. Use colmnindex rather than hardcoding

Comment: I will try, but as the count value is 0, doesn't that mean it hasn't found anything to even retrieve columns for?